# NextJS useRouter() router.push with properties to redirect to route with properties

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In NextJS I'm implementing a Search page and a Results Table page. These are separate routes,

```
/search/page.tsx
/results/page.tsx
```

I need to make the Search component do the back-end fetch based on search criteria, and then once it has the results, redirect to the Results component with a prop/parameter holding the data to display. The Results component shouldn't have any knowledge of back-end fetches, it simply renders any dataset that it's given as a prop.

Suppose that in my Search submit handler I have

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const router = useRouter();

const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
   // ... Back-end fetch ...
   router.push('/results/'); // NEED TO PASS DATA PROP HERE
}
```

Is this possible? I found a thread [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17008) the says

> There is no way to pass data between pages with Next's router. You
> would have to either use query strings as you mentioned,
> sessionStorage, or a state management option like Redux or React's
> Context API.

Obviously I don't want to pass as a query string a large dataset. So what would be some simple solutions here, if I'm not using a dedicated state management system?

**Update: Just to confirm, has NextJS had any changes in this respect as of now (2024) since that [response](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17008) was given in 2020, and is there still no way to pass props to a route?** We can get by with **including** the child component in a parent component, but would prefer actual URLs with some prop-passing, and **NOT** URL params or Context.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple React context to share state between components. Here's a basic example,

```js
// Create a context file (e.g. MyContext.tsx)
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

type MyContextType = {
  searchData: any
  setSearchData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>
}

const MyContext = createContext<MyContextType | undefined>(undefined)

export const MyContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState<any>(null)

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ searchData, setSearchData }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useMyContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(MyContext)
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider')
  }
  return context
}
```

Then, you wrap your application or the specific components that need access to this context with MyContextProvider. You can use useMyContext in your components to access and update the shared state.

```js
import { useMyContext } from 'path-to-MyContext'

function someComponent() {
  const { searchData, setSearchData } = useMyContext()
  
  // set search data from first component then router.push to redirect.

  // access searchData from the second component and render it accordingly. 

  return <div> search content here</div>
}
```